# Accessing HTML elements by their id from an array of elements in Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to access HTML elements by their `id` from an array of HTML Elements. I created this array using the `getElementsByTagName` and I am trying to access these elements like this: `arrayName.getElementById("theId")`.

Basically this is what I am trying to implement:

In a Javascript function triggered by an onchange event I receive the reference to the element causing the trigger. Since its a table structure I get the reference to a `<td>` element.
Now I want to access all the other elements of the `<tr>` in which that `<td>` is, using the id of each individual element.

A small replica of my code:

```
function chngFunction(theTd){
    var thisRow = theTd.parentNode;
    var inputs = thisRow.getElementsByTagName("input");
    alert(inputs[0].value);///////////Currently what I am doing////
    alert(inputs[1].value);///////////Currently what I am doing////
    .
    .
    .
    //////// What I would like ////////
    //// alert(thisRow.getElementById("myId").value);  // or something like that////
    /////////////// OR ///////////////
    //// alert(inputs[].getElementById("myId").value); // or something like that////
    ///////////////////////////////////
```

This is what I want because, currently if I make any structural changes to my jsp, I have to make changes to js also (that can leave bugs). So using ids to access individual elements would be great.

Please help me out.

Comment: Are the IDs unique *across the whole document*? Please share more details.

Comment: td have onchange event ?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse : My table gets created by a struts Iterator so Ids are not same. What else can I share? Jsp page?

Comment: @SergeS : A textfield inside the td has an onchange event associated with it.

Comment: `id`s are supposed to be **globally unique** in HTML. `getElementById` will not work reliably across browsers otherwise. Also have a look at jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector) API.

This should work:

```
thisRow.querySelector('#myId');
```

And if your element ids are unique across the document (as they **should** be), you can just do `document.getElementById`.

Comment: Are you sure that this method works in InternetExplorer Chrome and Safari too?

Comment: The page lists browser version that support it.

Comment: @reporter: Support is quite good, but IE7 and earlier don't have it. More: http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector

Comment: We don't know which kind of Browser does the OP uses, so that's why I asked.

Comment: Thanks this is working perfectly fine. Browser requirements met. I did not understand the bug in firefox though.

Comment: @kanishk: What "bug in Firefox"?

Answer (score 4):

By definition, `id` values are [unique throughout the entire document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute). So there is no `HTMLElement#getElementById` that retrieves elements by ID from only that element's descendants. Instead, there's [`document.getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) that looks for them globally (since, again, `id` values are globally unique in the document). So if you're using `id` values:

```
alert(document.getElementById("myId").value);
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById` is a method of the `document` object, not nodes, so you must use it this way: `document.getElementById('id');` .

of course, this will only work if the HTML elements are attached to the DOM tree. In case they are'nt, you should use a selector API. like Sergio is suggesting in his answer.

Comment: Actually getElementById is a method of Node. It's typically just used on document, but it can also be used on a Node object that represents something other than the document.

Comment: are you sure of that ? node.getElementById is undefined on all implementations I've try it

Comment: Node is a type, not a pre-existing object. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/GgtaC/

Comment: that's precisely why I advise not using prototypeJS and mootools libraries: http://jsfiddle.net/GgtaC/1/ . getElementById is definitely not a method of Node objects.

Comment: @kinakuta so you mean I can use getElementById on my variable `thisRow` which represents a row node?

Comment: Because ID's are unique you wouldn't need it to be a method of a node. Just use it on the document and there's no problem?

Comment: BiAiB is correct - I've fallen prey to Mootools wrapping elements and providing getElementById. Ignore what I said.

Comment: @Alex : Since my table get generated by struts iterator, the ids are not unique as they ideally should be

Comment: So I guess I will go with selector API as Sergio has mentioned.

Comment: @kanishk be aware of selector API compatibility: I'm not sure here but I thinks it's like FF3+ IE9+ Chrome Safari, so users locked with IE8/7/6 won't experience the functionnality. best thing to do here is to use some JS library selector API. In jQuery you'd do: $('#myId') or $("*[id='myId']"). haven't test the latter but I think it might not assume uniqueness and in-document attchment.

Comment: @BiAiB : I am late in replying, but since the ids on my jsp are not unique, how will the jquery come to know which particular element's value to pick.

Comment: @kanishk best is test yourself. I don't how all browsers act in this case. Can't you switch your id on another attribute such as: <tr rowid="xxx"> to be conform, then use $('tr[rowid=xxx]') ?